# Direct all HTML extension-less URL's to HTML extension-having URL's via .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I've found a couple similar questions asked before, but none with a concrete solution it seems. What I'm after is as follows; in the rare cases where a visitor forgets to add the .html extension to the end of a url (typing everything else in the string properly however), I'd like them to be directed to the page they were aiming for, *with* the .html extension.

Possible?

Current .htaccess code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

#Canonical
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Blocking
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from 123.151.39.
    Deny from 186.219.44.6
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.crimea\.com [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} s368\.loopia\.se [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} kanagawa\.ocn [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (huaweisymantecspider|sitesnagger|spam|sucker|webcopier|webreaper|webstripper) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sure, it's called URL rewriting. I believe it is only possible if (on Apache httpd) mod_rewrite is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the following a try.

I have also simplified your code a little (first check for `www.`, then remove `index.html`, then add the `.html` extension if the file actually exists.)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Force www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

    # Remove index.html
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [R=301,L]

    # Add .html extension if file exists
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [R=301,L]
</IfModule>


# Blocking
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from 123.151.39.
    Deny from 186.219.44.6
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.crimea\.com [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} s368\.loopia\.se [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} kanagawa\.ocn [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (huaweisymantecspider|sitesnagger|spam|sucker|webcopier|webreaper|webstripper) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|png|gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,R=301]
```

1. We d'ont want to add .html after js or css files extension
2. We check that the url doesn't already contain .html extension
3. We check that the url isn't empty

Instead of listing acceptable extensions you can filter on url not containing a `.` character.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I've removed inline comment from those examples, you can try again.